# como fazer para pegar dados de uma tabela mysql e inserir em outra :?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-update

Estou tentando fazer validador de pincode (serial), mas não sei como fazer.

Tenho duas tabelas: "validacao" e "vencimento".

Na tabela "validacao", tem os seguintes campos:

```
id(int), data(varchar), pincode(varchar), status(int)
```

Na tabela "vencimento", tem os seguintes campos:

```
id(int), data(varchar)
```

Queria pegar os dados da tabela validacao (data) e fazer update na tabela vencimento mais so ira fazer update se o serial estiver certo ao digitar !
e se o status etiver 0 !

```
exemplo: 
0 = ainda não ativou!
1 = ja foi ativado !
```

alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Comment: O que você quer é  montar uma query que atualize as duas tabelas, é isso?

Comment: sim ! e pq estou tentando fazer um ativador de serial so porque nao sei como fazer !

Comment: nao entendi ! ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumindo que o `id` seja `autoincrement`:

```
INSERT INTO vencimento(data)
SELECT v.data
  FROM validacao v
 WHERE v.pincode = 'xxxxxxx'
   and v.status = 0;
```

Comment: Simples assim? Caramba! Eu já estava imaginando uma daquelas querys cheias de subquerys e é até relativamente simples.

Comment: @diegofm Nada, praticamente em todos os bancos dá pra você inserir de uma tabela na outra só com `select`. Geralmente no instinto a gente coloca o `values` pra testar e não funciona.

Comment: Sarock poderia me ajudar ?

Comment: Funcionou nao Sorack !

Comment: Qual erro que deu?

Comment: nao deu nada e tambem nao inseriu nada !

Comment: meu codigo esta assim http://pastebin.com/ZucDrr2i queria colocar isso nesse codigo poderia me ajudar ?

Comment: mas vc passou o pincode como parametro? o `xxxxxxxx` era só um exemplo

Comment: passei o pincode com parametro que esta no banco 
INSERT INTO vencimento(data)
SELECT v.data
  FROM validacao v
 WHERE v.pincode = 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e'
   and v.status = 1;

Comment: @RooOliveira voce quer que ele faça por você? Acho até louvavel ele te ajudar, mas jogar o código e dizer "faz pra mim" não vai fazer você  aprender e não é muito o foco do site. Se está complicado fazer, talvez seja interessante rever o que você sabe e o que precisa aprender antes de ir para coisas mais avançadas, e ir fazendo os mais simples.

Comment: nao estou querendo que ele faça por mim so quero uma breve explicaçao

Comment: sim entendo mais um explicação seria bom !

Comment: @RooOliveira Testa direto no seu banco primeiro pra ver se vai funcionar. É sempre bom quebrar o problema em pedaços menores pra ficar mais fácil de resolver

Comment: consegui deu certo mais ! estou tentando fazer estou sem logica !
http://pastebin.com/7kfDrfHD

Comment: @RooOliveira Qualquer coisa abre outra pergunta com a dúvida que surgiu

Comment: abri outra !...