# É possível dar insert com select?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho duas tabelas:

```
hardware(ID, DEVICEID, NAME, ...)
```

e

```
softwares(ID, HARDWARE_ID, PUBLISHER, NAME, VERSION, ETC ...).
```

Preciso dar insert na tabela softwares, porém não tenho o `HARDWARE_ID`, recebo apenas o nome do hardware (`hardware.NAME`), esse `HARDWARE_ID` é o que faz o relacionamento entre as tabelas.

Não quero dar select na `hardware where name = $software['server_name']` para cada linha de registro, estou criando uma API que irá incluir arrays de softwares enviados via JSON.

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: bom você vai ter que fazer a busca do HARDWARE_ID de alguma forma. se não for através do select, veja a possibilidade de receber o id no json.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [como fazer para pegar dados de uma tabela mysql e inserir em outra :?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166584/como-fazer-para-pegar-dados-de-uma-tabela-mysql-e-inserir-em-outra)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sim, é possível realizar um `insert` utilizando um `select`.

```
`INSERT INTO software (HARDWARE_ID, PUBLISHER, NAME, VERSION) 
SELECT ID, 'TEXTO PUBLISHER', 'TEXTO NAME', 'TEXTO VERSION' 
FROM hardware hw WHERE hw.NAME = 'NOME HARDWARE';`
```

Ao realizar o `INSERT` com select o MySQL utilizará os retornos do `SELECT` como valores à serem inseridos.

Tome cuidado com a geração da chave primária da tabela software, se a chave não for gerada por um `AUTO_INCREMENT` ou trigger, o retorno do `SELECT` deverá gerar uma chave para cada linha.

Se quiser relacionar mais de um hardware por vez invés de `WHERE hw.NAME = 'NOME HARDWARE'` altere o filtro do `SELECT` para trazer N hardwares por vez. `WHERE hw.NAME IN ('NOME HARDWARE', 'NOME HARDWARE 2')`

[MySQL 5.7 DOC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!