# SELECT seguindo de INSERT

Tags: php, mysql

Eu preciso inserir a latitude da cidade, na latitude da embarcação, então eu fiz isso.

```
function cadastrarEmbarcacao($nome, $capacidade, $cidadePartida, $cidadeChegada, $horaViagem, $diaViagem){

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT CID_LATITUDE FROM cidade");

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO embarcacao (EMB_NOME, EMB_CAPACIDADE, EMB_LATITUDE) VALUES ('$nome', '$capacidade', '$sql')") or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<script>alert('Embarcação Cadastrada com Sucesso!!');location.href='../view/cadastrarEmbarcacao.php';</script>";
}
```

Alguém pode me dar uma luz? Porque eu não sei o que fazer.

Comment: De um olhada aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/167090/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-dar-insert-com-select

Comment: Qual o retorno apenas do seu select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes fazer um insert com select.

```php
<?php 
mysql_query("insert into embarcacao(EMB_NOME, EMB_CAPACIDADE, EMB_LATITUDE) select '$nome', '$capacidade', CID_LATITUDE from cidade;");
```

Comment: Rafael Nery, Obrigado!